# Generate a "Sudoku like" HTML Table with PHP

Tags: php, html, html-table

Here is a very simple [Sudoku like HTML table](http://pastie.org/1309688).

What I want is to generate this with PHP considering the following.

Each cell should look like this (or similar):

```
<!-- Position "a1" -->

<?php
if ($a1_pos_txt !== TRUE){

    echo "<td>" . $numbers["a1_pos"] . "</td>";

}else{

?>

<td><input type="text" name="a1_post" size="1" maxlength="1" /></td>

<?php   
}
?>
```

This is obviously the the "a1" cell.

Just in case, "c4" and "f9" should look like [THIS](http://pastie.org/1309713).

So the table generated by PHP should look like [THIS](http://pastie.org/1309721) and so on for all the rows.

As I said, and dont want to copy and paste this code and replace a1 for a2 and so on 81 times, I want his table and variables to be dynamically generated with PHP.

I tried to make it as clear as possible with all the code I could provide but please ask if you need any clarifications!!!

NOTE: Sorry for the crappy choice in variables (`$a1_pos_txt` , `$a1_pos` and `a1_post`) no vert friendly :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it:

```
$lit = range('A', 'J');
echo '<table border="1">';
for($y = 0; $y < 9; $y++) {
    echo '<tr>';
    for($x = 0; $x < 9; $x++) {
        $block = floor($x / 3) + floor($y / 3) * 3;
        $cell  = ($x % 3 + 1) + ($y % 3) * 3;
        echo '<td>'.$lit[$block].$cell.'</td>';
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```

Output:

```
A1 A2 A3 B1 B2 B3 C1 C2 C3
A4 A5 A6 B4 B5 B6 C4 C5 C6
A7 A8 A9 B7 B8 B9 C7 C8 C9
D1 D2 D3 E1 E2 E3 F1 F2 F3
D4 D5 D6 E4 E5 E6 F4 F5 F6
D7 D8 D9 E7 E8 E9 F7 F8 F9
G1 G2 G3 H1 H2 H3 I1 I2 I3
G4 G5 G6 H4 H5 H6 I4 I5 I6
G7 G8 G9 H7 H8 H9 I7 I8 I9
```

Probably can be simplified down a bit, but should give you what you need. `$block` is the current 3x3 grid, and `$cell` is the cell number in that grid.

**EDIT**

I checked your example and this might not be what you wanted. Apparently you want A for first row, B for second etc, not per 3x3 block. Here's how you can do that:

```
echo '<table border="1">';
foreach(range('A', 'J') as $y) {
    echo '<tr>';
    for($x = 1; $x <= 9; $x++) {
        echo '<td>'.$y.$x.'</td>';
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```

Output:

```
A1 A2 A3 A4 A5 A6 A7 A8 A9
B1 B2 B3 B4 B5 B6 B7 B8 B9
C1 C2 C3 C4 C5 C6 C7 C8 C9
D1 D2 D3 D4 D5 D6 D7 D8 D9
E1 E2 E3 E4 E5 E6 E7 E8 E9
F1 F2 F3 F4 F5 F6 F7 F8 F9
G1 G2 G3 G4 G5 G6 G7 G8 G9
H1 H2 H3 H4 H5 H6 H7 H8 H9
I1 I2 I3 I4 I5 I6 I7 I8 I9
J1 J2 J3 J4 J5 J6 J7 J8 J9
```

Comment: Thanks for the update I trying to undertand it and apply it. Thank you!!

Comment: The only this is that what i actually wanted to generate are not the "a1" "b2" examples I´m modifying your code for this case in particular, thanks for putting me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

PHP supports arrays of arrays (or matrix). Create an array from 0 to 8, and each value should also be an array from 0 to 8.

When your 9x9 matrix is constructed - figure out which values you want to be answered and set those to true `$answers[1][3] = true`

Then create 2 for-loops and print out your entire table. Your outter for loop will have to print `<tr>` tags too.

Comment: Ok thanks, I think I get your approach but I´m not sure what you mean by: "figure out which values you want to be answered" Sorry, Thanks!!